# Convert string date to timestamp in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a string `2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00` which i want to convert into timestamp format before storing to database. anyone can help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? We're happy to help, but you need to make an attempt to solve the issue yourself :)

Comment: use this `date('d -m -Y',strtotime('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00'))` ..

Comment: or use this `date('Y -m -d',strtotime('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00'))`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Carbon::parse('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00')->toDateTimeString();

// OR

Carbon::parse('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Result: `2020-09-18 07:58:03`

Comment: Actually i want to get a timestamp like this 2020-09-22 14:59:11

Comment: `2020-09-22 14:59:11` This is not timestamp check the update answer

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick if you want a timestamp:

```
Carbon::parse('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00')->timestamp;
```

But I don't think that you need a timestamp to store the date. Parsing should be enough.

```
$model->my_date_field = Carbon::parse('2020-09-18T07:58:03-04:00');
$model->save();
```